# what is the meaning of $F_{z_{T}}(f_{x,y,z_{T}})$ (fourier transform of a matrix with respect to one dimention)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

What is the meaning of $F_{z_{T}}(f_{x,y,z_{T}})$ (Fourier transform of a matrix with respect to one dimension)? $f_{x,y,z_{T}}$ is just a 3D matrix. It would be great if you bring me the formula.